# Centre manifold non-hyperbolic fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following dynamical system $\dot x=-x^3, \dot y=-y$.

I would like to prove that there are an infinite number of trajectories that become tangent to the line $y=0$ for $x\rightarrow 0$. Each of the trajectories is a centre manifold and they satisfy $y=h(x)$ where all possible forms of $h$ have zero taylor expansiion about origin.

First of all we know that the line $y=0$ is invariant. The only fixed point is $(0,0)$, the eigenvalues are $-1,0$ with Eigenvectors $(0,1), (1,0)$.

How can I proceed? Do I have to find some guess for $h(x)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just solve for $h(x)$ directly.

$x$ will satisfy

$$\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-2} - C_1 = t$$

and $y$

$$ y = C_2e^{-t}. $$

Combine these expressions to get $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: Ok, so I get $y=ce^{c/2-1/(2x^2)}$, you are saying that this is $h(x)$, right? But does it follow now that there are an infinite number of trjaectories that become tangent to the line y=0 as x goes to 0 ?

Comment: I think so. If you take the derivative of that (i.e. $dy/dx$) then the result should $\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ independent of the constants.